# Drag objects outside the browser window

Tags: java, javascript, flash, html, plugins

Is it possible to drag objects outside the browser window in order to implement file/directory copying from webserver to desktop?

UPDATE: added more tags in order to broaden the choice of methods.

Comment: I'd take a look at the Google Gears.

Comment: @Peeter thats not on topic with the question asked.

Comment: @Stefan: Why not? Google gears adds quite a bit of functionality to the browser that you wouldn't normally have. From google gears site: "Let web applications interact naturally with your desktop".

Comment: @Peeter It's a browser extension, you can prety much do anything with a browser extension but the main issue is the compatibility/support. This question was flagged js/jquery/html5. Otherwise, yes you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

With javascript and jquery? No. Since these are rendered in the browser, they stop working outside the browser. This is something that has to be implemented by the browser itself, or in the operating system.

Comment: Iam upvoting this but iam not really sure if HTML5 has controllers that supports this or not. It already works for simple links with proper MIME-types in most browsers. But relying on it is a no-no :)

Comment: @Henno Well it wasn't what you originally asked for. You need to format a question to make google gears an option. As it is now with your tags it is not. It will not work for everyone.

Comment: @Henno, I don't know much about how gears work. They aren't really javascript or jquery, though.

Comment: @stefan I edited the question and added more tags. The goal is to offer d&d from/to browser window with maximum compatibility and minimal user annoyance (from having to install or configure something)